# Angularjs ng-show doesn't work with Viewbag

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

In Angularjs template is it possible to use ViewBag.Property in ng-show?

I set some viewbag in my controller/action like this

```
ViewBag.AllowExport = false;
```

when i tried following nothing happen

```
 <div ng-show="@ViewBag.AllowExport">
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);">Export</a>
 </div>
```

Above Div is still showing even if AllowExport = false;

Is my syntax is wrong here or we can not use Viewbag in ng-show?

Any advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <div ng-show="'@(ViewBag.AllowExport)'">
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);">Export</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: This won't work since it'll be interpreted as a string 'false' resulting in the expression result being true...

Comment: Ok - good if it works for you ;) I just tested `<div ng-show="'false'">Test</div>` and the element was still shown...

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing fron-tend (Angular/JavaScript) and back-end (Razor) code here. I would strongly advice against that. However if you really want to do that: the result in HTML will be  which will just be a string to Angular.

This should work instead since Angular will validate the expression in `{{}}`:

```
<div ng-show="{{@ViewBag.AllowExport}}">
    <a href="">Export</a>
</div>
```

Instead of mixing in Razor syntax in your Angular HTML code I would recommend using a scope variable being set from either some JSON source, or if you really want to mix in MVC data, setting the value in some Javascript configuration:

```
<script>
    window.ClientConfig = {
        allowExport: @ViewBag.AllowExport,
    };
</script>
```

Then in your Angular controller simply use `$scope.allowExport = window.ClientConfig.allowExport;`

And in HTML:

```
<div ng-show="allowExport">
    <a href="">Export</a>
</div>
```

Comment: so you suggest to set some variable in $scope and use it in ng-show? and  by the way ng-show="{{@ViewBag.AllowExport}}" not working

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like? I just tested `ng-show="{{true}}"` and `ng-show="{{false}}"` and that worked. For the other part I'll extend the answer.